# How to specify default value for List<> parameter in a c# function?

Tags: c#

I've got a C# method that takes a bunch of parameters, all of which have default values. One of the parameters is a List. I can't figure out how to specify that the List should default to empty. Here's what it looks like:

```
    public static void execute(
        String condition = "Unnamed condition",
        List<String> messages,
        Object actual    = null,
        Object expected  = null)
```

I can't quite figure out how to specify that messages should be empty by default. When I enter:

```
...
List<String> messages = new List<String> ()
...
```

it complains that "default parameter value for 'messages' must be a compile-time constant".

Any ideas?

Comment: BTW, parameter types should be as wide as possible.  It would be better to use `IList<string>` or (preferably) `IEnumerable<string>`

Comment: I've never found clear instructions anywhere on the accept mechanism. Looking at the FAQ, I'm not seeing info on it...?

Comment: @StephenGross, just tick the green box next to the answer that's most likely to help future visitors with the same problem. :)

Comment: I understand that the green box is there; what's not clear to me is the guidelines for upvote/downvote/accept. Are there any such guidelines written anywhere?

Comment: @StephenGross, consult the [how-to-ask](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask) section in the FAQ.

Comment: I saw a comment about using the default() function here, but it got deleted... Does anyone know if that would work?

Comment: @StephenGross, it was `default(List<string>)`. The default of a reference type is null, so it's just more obvious and readable to state null explicitly. To be clear, it's not going to give you a non-null result such as an emtpy list.

Comment: @Stephen: Yes, default(List<String>) == null, the default of any reference type is null.

Comment: @JamesMichaelHare, then you mean "no". :)

Comment: @bzlm: Sorry, I meant yes it would "work" as in compile, but no it won't "work" as in create an empty List<String>.  It would be logically identical to just saying = null.  :-)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Because default parameter values must be compile-time expressions, the only acceptable default parameter value for reference types is `null`.

You can get around this with an overload, though:

```
 public static void execute(String condition = "Unnamed condition")
 {
     execute(condition, new List<String>(), null, null);
 }
```

Or constructing a list if the argument is `null`.  If you must need a list and want to treat all `null` as an empty list, this would also handle if they called with `null` explicitly.

```
 public static void execute(String condition = "Unnamed condition",
        List<String> messages = null, Object actual = null,
        Object expected = null)
{
    // if you really want this to be empty if null, can check and assign.
    if (messages == null)
    {
        messages = new List<String>();
    }

    // your other logic
}
```

Or, if messages is only used in one place, you can use the null-coallescing operator to substitute an empty enumeration:

```
 public static void execute(String condition = "Unnamed condition",
        List<String> messages = null, Object actual = null,
        Object expected = null)
{
    // assuming you are using messages once for iteration or something...
    foreach(var msg in messages ?? Enumerable.Empty<String>())
    ...
}
```

Though obviously a simple if-guard can be more efficient.  Really depends if you want to treat it as an empty enumerable or as an empty list or just bypass logic...

Answer (score 3):

As the error message clearly states, you can't arbitrary instances of reference types as default values.
All you can use are literals, `const`s, or `null`.

Instead, you can set the default to `null`, then write

```
messages = messages ?? new List<string>();
```

Answer (score 2):

Make `messages` default to `null` as well, and within the function body check whether its `null` and handle it appropiately (or replace it with a `new List()`).

Answer (score 2):

The only thing the compiler will accept here is null. If it is convenient for you, your method will need to test for this case and substitute an empty list:

```
if(messages==null) {
  messages=new List<String>();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The compiler is telling you why: default arguments must be compile-time constants. Obviously a dynamically allocated and constructed list doesn't fit that description. The simplest work-around is to make the default value `null`, and then in your method, if the argument is `null`, create the actual default list.